# How can I create a multi-gigabit link between these switches?

Tags: switch, hp, trunk

I have a server rack with an HP 2810-24G in it, and a data cabinet with an HP 1800-24G.

All the clients connect with gigabit to the 1800-24G, and all the servers are connected with gigabit to the 2810-24G. How can I create a multi-gigabit link between the switches so that more than one client can reach the server at gigabit speeds simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your switches support `IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation Protocol (LACP) and HP port trunking`

This is the feature specifically made to do what you want, it combines several physical links into a single logical one. This provide both additional bandwidth and fault-tolerance.

On the 1810 model this is limited to 4 link per trunk. (source: [this datasheet](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA2-6799ENW&doctype=data%20sheet&doclang=EN_US&searchquery=&cc=us&lc=en))

So you can have 4Gbs between the 2 switches.

Note that:

- LACP works by balancing different flows between links. A single flow will pass on a single link (so 1Gbs max).
- The term "trunk" used by HP in context of LACP can lead to confusion, it has nothing to do with the "trunk" mode of operation related to VLANs